# React - accessing a collection of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am downloading data from Firebase and it's in a form of object collection. I want to display certain items from there, based on the `props.id` value.

I do it like this:

```
export default class Ingredient extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.id = this.props.id;
    this.db = new Firebase('https://xxx.firebaseio.com/ingredients');

    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.db.on('value', (data) => {
      this.setState({
        loaded: true,
        data: data.val()
      });
    });
  }

  getElement() {
    return this.state.data[this.props.id];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      /*  - {this.state.data[this.props.id].name} */
      <strong>
        {this.getElement()}
      </strong>
    )
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, React returns an error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child

I don't quite understand what I did wrong here, can someone help me out?

Comment: The reason is because React.children can contain only strings or an HTML element or another React component. Your `getElement()` is returning neither of those - it's returning an object. What's the data-type of `this.state.data[<some_key>]` ? I suspect that `this.state.data` is an array of objects, not strings.

Comment: What do you see in console.log(this.state.data[this.props.id];)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue. It turned out the problem wasn't with the object, but with the data itself. When it wasn't downloaded, it would return said error.

My solution was the simplest possible:

```
  render() {
    if(this.state.loaded) {
      return <span>{this.state.data[this.props.id].name}</span>;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I have discarded the `getElement` method as well, since it's not necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

The `getElement` method returns the received data, which is an `object` and that is not a valid React element, meaning it cannot be directly rendered. Only a React element, or primitive value that has natural string representation can be rendered in the tree, meaning if your data has a `name` string property, this would work:

```
<strong>
 {this.getElement().name}
</strong>
```

Comment: I did try this method and it returns `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` (for both `name` and `slug`, which are there for sure).

Comment: That would be the case if `this.state.data[this.props.id]` does not exist. Just check if it does and return something sane if not.

Comment: Well, when I `console.log` it, it returns proper object with both `name` and `slug` values.

Comment: Sure, but only _after_ the data are loaded, not before. And the first rendering probably happens before the data comes in, so you have to take care of the possibility that the data object is not there yet.